# multithreaded iteration over numpy array indices

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, numpy

I have a piece of code which iterates over a three-dimensional array and writes into each cell a value based on the indices and the current value itself:

```
import numpy as np
nx = ny = nz = 100

array = np.zeros((nx, ny, nz))

def fun(val, k):
    # Do something with the indices
    return val + (k[0] * k[1] * k[2])

with np.nditer(array, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
    for x in it:
        x[...] = fun(x, it.multi_index)
```

Note, that `fun` might do something more sophisticated, which takes most of the total runtime, and that the input arrays might have different lengths per axis.

However, this code could run in multiple threads, as `fun` can be assumed to be threadsafe (Only the value and index of the current cell are required). But finding a method to iterate over all cells and have the current index available seems to be hard.

A possible solution might be https://stackoverflow.com/a/58012407/446140, where the array is split by the x-axis into chunks and passed to a `Pool`.
However, the solution is not universally applicable and I wonder if there is a more general solution for this problem (which could also work with nD arrays)?
The first issue is to split up the 3D array into equally sized chunks. [np.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) can be used, but the offset of each of the splits has to be stored to get the correct indices again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting question, with a few possible solutions. As you indicated, it is possible to use `np.array_split`, but since we are only interested in the indices, we can also use [np.unravel_index](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html), which would mean that we only have to loop over all the indices (the size) of the array to get the index.

Now there are two great ideas for multiprocessing:

1. Create a (thread safe) shared memory of the array and splitting the indices across the different processes.
2. Only update the array in a main thread, but provide a copy of the required data to the processes and let them return the value that has to be updated.

Both solutions will work for any `np.ndarray`, but have different advantages. Creating a shared memory doesn't create copies, but can have a large insertion penalty if it has to wait on other processes (the computational time, is small compared to the write time.)

There are probably many more solutions, but I will work out the first solution, where a Shared Memory object is created and a range of indices is provided to every process.

Required imports:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
```

### Shared Numpy arrays

The main problem with applying multiprocessing on `np.ndarray`'s  is that memory sharing between processes can be difficult. For this the following class can be used:

```
class SharedNumpy:
    __slots__ = ('arr', 'shm', 'name', 'shared',)

    def __init__(self, arr: np.ndarray = None):
        if arr is not None:
            self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=arr.nbytes)
            self.arr = np.ndarray(arr.shape, dtype=arr.dtype, buffer=self.shm.buf)
            self.name = self.shm.name
            np.copyto(self.arr, arr)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if hasattr(self.arr, item):
            return getattr(self.arr, item)
        raise AttributeError(f"{self.__class__.__name__}, doesn't have attribute {item!r}")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.arr)

    @classmethod
    def from_name(cls, name, shape, dtype):
        memory = cls(arr=None)
        memory.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name)
        memory.arr = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=memory.shm.buf)
        memory.name = name
        return memory

    @property
    def dtype(self):
        return self.arr.dtype

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return self.arr.shape
```

This makes it possible to create a `shared memory` object in the main process and then use `SharedNumpy.from_name` to get it in other processes.

#### Simple test

A quick (non threaded) test would be:

```
def simple_test():
    data = np.array(np.zeros((5,) * 2))

    mem_primary = SharedNumpy(arr=data)
    mem_second = SharedNumpy.from_name(name=mem_primary.name, shape=data.shape, dtype=data.dtype)

    assert mem_primary.name == mem_second.name, "Different memory names"
    assert np.array_equal(mem_primary.arr, mem_second.arr), "Different array values."

    mem_primary.arr[2] = 5
    assert np.array_equal(mem_primary.arr, mem_second.arr), "Different array values."
    print("Completed 3/3 tests...")
```

A threaded test will follow later!

### Distribution

The next part is focused on providing the processes with the necessary data. In this case we will provide every process with a range of indices that it has to calculate and all the data that is required to load the shared memory.

The input of this function is a `dim` the number of numpy axis, and the `size`, which are the number of elements per axis.

```
def distributed(size, dim):
    memory = SharedNumpy(arr=np.zeros((size,) * dim))
    split_size = np.int64(np.ceil(memory.arr.size / mp.cpu_count()))

    settings = dict(
            memory=itertools.repeat(memory.name),
            shape=itertools.repeat(memory.arr.shape),
            dtype=itertools.repeat(memory.arr.dtype),
            start=np.arange(mp.cpu_count()),
            num=itertools.repeat(split_size)
    )

    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pool.starmap(fun, zip(*settings.values()))

    print(f"\n\nDone {dim}D, size: {size}, elements: {size ** dim}")
    return memory
```

Notes:

- By using `starmap` instead of `map`, it is possible to provide multiple input arguments (a list of arguments for every process).

  - (also see [docs starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap))
- `itertools.repeat` is used to add constants to the `starmap`

  - (also see: [zip() in python, how to use static values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743490/zip-in-python-how-to-use-static-values))
- By using `np.unravel_index`, we only need to have a start index and the chunk size per process.
- The `start` and `num` tell the chunks of indices that have to be converted per process, by applying `range(start * num, (start + 1) * num)`.

### Testing

For the testing I am using different input sizes and dimensions. Since the data increases with the formula `sizes ^ dimensions`, I limited the test to a size of 128 and 3 dimensions (that is 2,097,152 points, and already start taking quit a bit of time.)

#### Code

- `fun`

  ```
  def fun(name, shape, dtype, start, num):
      memory = SharedNumpy.from_name(name, shape=shape, dtype=dtype)
      for idx in range(start * num, min((start + 1) * num, memory.arr.size)):
          # Do something with the indices
          indices = np.unravel_index([idx], shape)
          memory.arr[indices] += np.product(indices)
      memory.shm.close() # Closes the shared memory for this process.
  ```
- Running the example

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      for size in [5, 10, 15]:
          for dim in [1, 2, 3]:
              memory = distributed(size, dim)
              print(memory)
              memory.shm.unlink()
  ```

For the OP's code, I used his code with a small addition that I allow the array to have different sizes and dimensions, in any case I use:

```
def sequential(size, dim):
    array = np.zeros((size,) * dim)
    ...
```

And looking at the output array of both codes, will result in the same outcomes.

#### Plots

The code for the graphs have been taken from the reply in:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165245/plot-timings-for-a-range-of-inputs

With the minor alteration that `labels` was changed to `codes` in

```
empty_multi_index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[], []], codes=[[], []], names=['func', 'result'])
```

Where the `1d`, `2d` and `3d` reference the dimensions and the input is the `size`.

- Sequentially (OP code):
  [image: Sequential time for increasing input and different dimensions]
- Distributed (this code):
  [image: Distributed time for increasing input and different dimensions]

### Results

This method works on an arbitrary sized numpy array, and is able to perform an operation on the indices of the array. It provides you with full access of the whole numpy array, so it can also be used to perform different kind of statistical analysis, which do not change the array.

From the timings it can be seen that for small data shapes the distributed version has no to little advantages, because of the extra complexity of creating the processes. However for larger amount of data it starts to become more effective.

I only timed it on short delays in the computational time (simple `fun`), but on more complex calculations, it should outperform the sequential version much sooner.

### Extra

If you are only interested in operations that are performed over or along axis, these numpy functions might help to vectorize your solutions instead of using multiprocessing:

- [np.apply_over_axes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html)
- [np.apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine! However, I found out that my CPU slows down when all cores are used. When only a single core is used, I have around 4.2GHz, while with all four (not used HT) I have 3.5GHz. That does influence the result heavily. I had several tests and in most of them the distributed would be slower... Sometimes though it is faster. I'll test that now on a server with more cores.

Comment: I just found one issue with the code: `memory = cls(arr=np.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype))` creates a new shared memory but never closes it. Idk what the best method is here, but I changed the constructor to not create the object if `arr` is `None`.

Comment: @reox, on your first comment, multiprocessing is only advantageous, if the computational time takes much langer than the writing and reading of memory. Secondly the code is using shared memory, so there is a syncing stage / locking stage using the code (which limits the speed). That not closing issue is worrying and I updated the answer to properly close and unlink the memory after usage.