# Multiprocessing Pool ran the code that's not in the defined part several times

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pycharm, python-multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing for the function I defined ("my_function"). But when I ran the code and print finished steps as a hint of where I am in the program (such as print("file read") for the first reading file function) and the code are NOT in my_function, I can see the "file read" multiple times in the output equals to the number I input in the multiprocessing.Pool() + 1 (i.e., input 3 the file is read 4 times, input 1 the file is read 2 times).

I have no idea what happened here, I tried to put all the other functions in another .py file, however, the same issue appears again. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

```
import multiprocessing
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np


# load the dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt("dataset.txt")
print("==== data is loaded ====")
row, col = dataset.shape

# create dictionary
number_rule = defaultdict(int)
good_rule = defaultdict(int)

# define a function called my_function
def my_function(i):
    print(i)
    data = dataset[i]
    for j in range(col):
        if data[i] == 0:
            continue
        number_rule[i] += 1
        for j in range(col):
            if i == j:
                continue
            if data[j] == 1:
                good_rule[(i, j)] += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # multiprocessing with 3 process (4 CPU in local computer)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    for i in range(row):
        pool.apply_async(my_function,[i])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

When I ran the code, this line"==== data is loaded ====" was printed 4 times, meaning my dataset was loaded 4 times. This causes the problem for me running the code for my whole dataset (currently I sliced the dataset to be small to try the code, the whole dataset is big and thus when it is loaded several time, it crashes my computer).

Comment: your code is incomplete, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. In this case that includes a basic `my_function` and the received output compared to the expected output.

Comment: Hi, I edited the code and provided the minimal reproducible example here. Hope this can help you understand my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The reason for the 4 times loading of the data, is that you are calling the dataset inside the function, therefore everything has to be copied. You can either pass only the relevant section to the mp pool, or you can use a shared array. For the shared numpy array take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66878746/10961342) post which helps you create a memory efficient shared numpy array.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Isn't the data read already stored in the memory? I thought as this code "pool.apply_async(my_function,[i])" specifically saying I only need multiprocessing for "my_function", it will retrieve the data loaded in the memory and start multiprocessing. Are you saying that when encountered the code "dataset[i]" in "my_function", the multiprocessing will start to go up to find the dataset variable and execute the loading again? 

If this is the case, how can I pass the function to the mp pool without triggering it running the loading again? Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately that is not entirely how multiprocessing works. As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) mention, sharing states between processes is best avoid. For a more detailed explanation try [this](https://blog.floydhub.com/multiprocessing-vs-threading-in-python-what-every-data-scientist-needs-to-know/) blog about the difference between threading and multiprocessing or the realpython guide about [concurrency](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/).